# MySQL - Int forcing all values to be the same

Tags: mysql

I have created a Payment database.

My CardNo column is of datatype INT.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
 | Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
 | Payment_ID | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | null    |       | 
 | CardNo     | int(16)     | YES  |     | null    |       | 
 | ExpiryDate | varchar(45) | YES  |     | null    |       | 
 | Guest_ID   | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | null    |       | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

However this is forcing all my int values to be the same.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
 | Payment_ID | CardNo     | ExpiryDate | Guest_ID | 
-----------------------------------------------------
 | 1          | 2147483647 | 09/19      | 1        | 
 | 2          | 2147483647 | 04/18      | 2        | 
 | 3          | 2147483647 | 09/18      | 3        | 
 | 4          | 2147483647 | 01/20      | 4        | 
 | 5          | 2147483647 | 04/21      | 5        | 
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this? I can't find one online? 
When I alter the column to a Varchar(16) I can see the actual value I've entered.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
 | Payment_ID | CardNo           | ExpiryDate | Guest_ID | 
-----------------------------------------------------------
 | 1          | 1234567891234567 | 09/19      | 1        |
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question, so I'll just ask you to note that the number in parenthesis following the INT keyword has almost no meaning in MySQL. That said, it sounds to me like what you actually want *is* a string, and not an integer. Also, note that the maximum value for an unsigned integer is 2147483647, as per the manual.

Comment: A VARCHAR is a better data type than INT for storing credit card numbers.

PS. You should not store credit card numbers without a lot of security precautions...

Comment: Good grief - I hope these aren't bank cards!!

Comment: INT default size is 10 only but you using 16. Better you can use BIGINT instead of INT

Comment: And my one more suggestion is don't specify any size for BIGINT

Comment: Storing credit cart #s in cleartext is [extremely bad practice](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf) and possibly illegal. When you get hacked and the bad guys get your database, you may even be liable for damages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max value for an INT column is 2147483647

[See Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

You have 2 options. Change it to a BIGINT or change it to a CHAR (the length probably won't change so just have a fixed size column).

Personally I have always used CHAR.